# Insert data from server to SQLite Database

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am inserting 3000 plus data from my server to my SQLite Database. The problem is the inserting process is very slow. Is there a better way to insert the data efficiently and effectively? What I am doing is I converted the data I got from my server to JSON Object and insert it one-by-one. I know what I am doing is inefficient. How can I fix this?

```
public class AndroidSQLiteDb : ISQLiteDB
{
    public SQLiteAsyncConnection GetConnection()
    {
        var dbFileName = "backend.db3";
        var documentsPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
        var path = Path.Combine(documentsPath, dbFileName);

        return new SQLiteAsyncConnection(path);
    }
}

public async void FirstSyncContacts(string host, string database, string contact)
    {
        try
        {
            var db = DependencyService.Get<ISQLiteDB>();
            var conn = db.GetConnection();

            var sql = "SELECT * FROM tblContacts WHERE Coordinator = '" + contact + "'";
            var getContacts = conn.QueryAsync<ContactsTable>(sql);
            var resultCount = getContacts.Result.Count;
            var current_datetime = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:00");

            //Check if the retailer has been sync
            if (resultCount < 1)
            {
                try
                {
                    syncStatus.Text = "Syncing Retailer";

                    var link = Constants.requestUrl + "Host=" + host + "&Database=" + database + "&Contact=" + contact + "&Request=9DpndD";
                    string contentType = "application/json";
                    JObject json = new JObject
                    {
                        { "ContactID", contact }
                    };

                    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
                    var response = await client.PostAsync(link, new StringContent(json.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, contentType));

                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                        if (content != "")
                        {
                            var contactsresult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ContactsData>>(content);

                            foreach (var item in contactsresult)
                            {
                                // update only the properties that you have to...

                                item.LastSync = Convert.ToDateTime(current_datetime);
                                item.ServerUpdate = Convert.ToDateTime(item.ServerUpdate);
                                item.MobileUpdate = Convert.ToDateTime(item.MobileUpdate);
                            }
                            await conn.InsertAsync(contactsresult);

                        }
                    }

                    //Proceed to next function
                    FirstSyncRetailerGroup(host, database, contact);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.Write("Syncing Retailer Error " + ex.Message);
                }
            }
            //If not get the retailer
            else
            {
                SyncContacts(host, database, contact);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.Write("Syncing Retailer Error " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Use the non-async `Insert` in one background thread, instead of 3000 separate async calls... create one instance of `ContactsTable` and reuse (reset/set all properties it on each insert loop iteration (will save a lot of GC time), no need to assign all those json properties (item.XXX) to another local variable, just to reassign them to the properties of the ContactsTable.

Comment: @SushiHangover can you show me how?

Comment: @SushiHangover I really need help

Comment: @LawrenceAgulto please avoid json in sqlite. SQLite only for your internal purpose. So you can manage without JSON. If you avoid this you can see the speed difference

Comment: @RanjithKumar how can I avoid this? Can you show me how?

Comment: Use Refit library - https://github.com/reactiveui/refit It will auto type casting to POJO class. so you can avoid JSON. try and tell me

Answer (score 1):

1. Use the non-async `Insert` in one background thread, instead of 3000 separate async calls...
2. Re-use the List from your DeserializeObject step instead of creating new local objects that will just be thrown away on each loop iteration.
3. No need to assign all those json properties (item.XXX) to another local variable, just update the properties of each existing `ContactsData` as needed before inserting it into the DB.

#### Example using `SQLiteConnection`:

```
// Use the non-async version of SQLiteConnection
var conn = new SQLiteConnection(dbPath, true, null);

// code removed for example...

await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(() =>
{
    var contactsresult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ContactsData>>(content);

    // start a transaction block so all 3000 records are committed at once.
    conn.BeginTransaction();

    // Use `foreach` in order shortcut the need to retrieve the object from the list via its index
    foreach (var item in contactsresult)
    {
        // update only the properties that you have to...

        item.LastSync = Convert.ToDateTime(current_datetime);
        item.ServerUpdate = Convert.ToDateTime(item.ServerUpdate);
        item.MobileUpdate = Convert.ToDateTime(item.MobileUpdate);

        conn.Insert(item);
    }
    conn.Commit();
});
```

#### Example using `SQLiteAsyncConnection`:

```
var db = DependencyService.Get<ISQLiteDB>();
var conn = db.GetConnection();

~~~

var contactsresult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ContactsData>>(content);

foreach (var item in contactsresult)
{
    // update only the properties that you have to...

    item.LastSync = Convert.ToDateTime(current_datetime);
    item.ServerUpdate = Convert.ToDateTime(item.ServerUpdate);
    item.MobileUpdate = Convert.ToDateTime(item.MobileUpdate);
}
conn.InsertAsync(contactsresult); // Insert the entire list at once...
```

Comment: I am using my code to sync data from my server into my sqlite database can I still use  var db = DependencyService.Get<ISQLiteDB>();
                var conn = db.GetConnection();

Comment: DependencyService? yes, just add a another Get that returns the non-async connection....

Comment: Can you show your complete code based on my code? I am so confused

Comment: *My* complete code? That code was written straight into Stackoverflow based upon your code

Comment: I mean can you modify this var conn = new SQLiteConnection(dbPath, true, null); and use this var db = DependencyService.Get<ISQLiteDB>();
            var conn = db.GetConnection();

Comment: I do not know how you implemented `ISQLiteDB`, add another "GetConnection", like GetNonAsyncConnection that calls SQLiteConnection vs SQLiteAsyncConnection.

Comment: Do i need to to put your answer inside public async void FirstSyncContacts(string host, string database, string contact)? and do i need var sql = "SELECT * FROM tblContacts WHERE Coordinator = '" + contact + "'";
            var getContacts = conn.QueryAsync<ContactsTable>(sql);
            var resultCount = getContacts.Result.Count;
            var current_datetime = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:00");?

Comment: And do I still need  var link = Constants.requestUrl + "Host=" + host + "&Database=" + database + "&Contact=" + contact + "&Request=9DpndD";
                        string contentType = "application/json";
                        JObject json = new JObject
                        {
                            { "ContactID", contact }
                        };

                        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
                        var response = await client.PostAsync(link, new StringContent(json.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, contentType));?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem so even the answer is some years late, maybe can be usefull for somebody.

This is how I did.

**First:** I get the data all from server as json

```
var response = await client.GetAsync("your_server_url");
var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
ResponseData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataModel>(content);
```

**Second:** Save data to database

```
await conn.InsertAllAsync(ResponseData)
```

**But in my case**, because our app works offline data, I first insert all data in a temp table, then I **get all new records** comparing main table with temp table.

```
NewDataFromTemp = await conn.QueryAsync<DataModel>("SELECT * FROM [TableTemp] t WHERE t.[TABLE_ID] NOT IN (SELECT g.[TABLE_ID] FROM [MainTable] g)");
```

And **insert new records** in Main table

```
await conn.InsertAllAsync(NewDataFromTemp)
```

Then I **check for updated records**

```
UpdatedDataFromTemp = await conn.QueryAsync<DataModel>("SELECT t.* FROM [TableTemp] t, [MainTable] o WHERE t.[TABLE_ID]=o.[TABLE_ID] AND t.[TABLE_UPDATED]>o.[TABLE_UPDATED]");
```

And **update all record** in main table

```
await conn.UpdateAllAsync(UpdatedDataFromTemp);
```

I use **logical delete** so when updating the logical delete will be updated too.